# Implementing Contiki -RPL on Arduino

Tags: contiki

Can any one help me ,please?

I am working on a project in which I need to implement RPL Contiki on Arduino cards. I have a problem in testing the simple-udp-rpl located in the contiki-arduino/examples/ipv6/ folder.

These are the steps that I 've followed:

Steps :-
1. # To compile the code make TARGET=arduino ARDUINO_MODEL=Uno

2.avr-objcopy unicast-sender.arduino -j .text -j .data -O ihex unicast-sender.hex

3. Connect the board with laptop and copy hex file to board.  avrdude -D -p atmega328p -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200  -U flash:w:unicast-sender.hex:i -v -C /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf
4. In console run the below command and reset your Arduino board
            ttylog -V -d /dev/ttyACM0 -b 9600

Unfortunately, it dosn't work, it is blocked in the step 3. These are the result of executing the command 3:

user@instant-contiki:~/contiki-arduino/examples/ipv6/simple-udp-rpl$ avr-objcopy unicast-sender.arduino -j .text -j .data -O ihex unicast-sender.hexuser@instant-contiki:~/contiki-arduino/examples/ipv6/simple-udp-rpl$ avrdude -D -p atmega328p -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200  -U flash:w:unicast-sender.hex:i -v -C /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 17:07:18
        Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
        Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
        User configuration file is "/home/user/.avrduderc"
        User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0

Using Programmer              : arduino

Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

AVR Part                      : ATmega328P

Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us

PAGEL                         : PD7

BS2                           : PC2

RESET disposition             : dedicated

RETRY pulse                   : SCK

serial program mode           : yes

parallel program mode         : yes

Timeout                       : 200

StabDelay                     : 100

CmdexeDelay                   : 25

SyncLoops                     : 32

ByteDelay                     : 0

PollIndex                     : 3

PollValue                     : 0x53

Memory Detail                 :
      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
  Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack

----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------

eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600 
 3600 0xff 0xff

flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500 
 4500 0xff 0xff

lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

Programmer Type : Arduino

Description     : Arduino

Hardware Version: 3

Firmware Version: 4.4

Vtarget         : 0.3 V

Varef           : 0.3 V

Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz

SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100%
0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0

avrdude: reading input file "unicast-sender.hex"

avrdude: ERROR: address 0x8010 out of range at line 2049 of unicast-sender.hex

avrdude: read from file 'unicast-sender.hex' failed

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as 0

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:00, E:00, L:00)

---

avrdude: ERROR: address 0x8010 out of range at line 2049 of unicast-sender.hex

avrdude: read from file 'unicast-sender.hex' failed

==> Do you have any ideas how can I resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Comment: Also, please edit your question and remove the quotes (>) from it, as it is visually disturbing to see it used all over your question, and reformat your question and code (using indentation) correctly